# JasperReport Server REST 2 api - Creating a new report

Tags: jasperserver

I was not able to find any api that can actually create a report on the JasperReports Server.

There is one to create resource.
http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-services-guide/v550/creating-resource

To an extend it tells about how to create a folder etc. but talks nothing about creating a report in all.

Any idea on how a report (jrxml) can be done in a programmatic way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To post your reports manually to the JasperServer repository, use the same method as in the link you posted, but you aren't posting a **resourceDescriptor**. You should be posting a **reportUnit** instead.

Here is an example of the PUT command where I'm sending a (gzipped) jrxml file I named TestJrxmlFile to the repository creating a new report:

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/jasperserver-pro/rest_v2/resources/public/TestJrxmlFile?createFolders=true&overwrite=true HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/repository.reportUnit+xml
User-Agent: Jersey/2.13 (Apache HttpClient 4.3.4)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=45F47838C567120CF4DB1068AE0473C4; userLocale=en_US
Cookie2: $Version=1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

82d
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><reportUnit><description>ds</description><label>TestJrxmlFile</label><permissionMask>1</permissionMask><uri>/public/TestJrxmlFile</uri><version>-1</version><alwaysPromptControls>true</alwaysPromptControls><controlsLayout>popupScreen</controlsLayout><resources/><inputControls/><jrxmlFile><label>Main jrxml</label><permissionMask>1</permissionMask><uri>/public/TestJrxmlFile_files/main_jrxml</uri><version>-1</version><content>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    Y2giLz4KCTwvcGFnZUZvb3Rlcj4KCTxzdW1tYXJ5PgoJCTxiYW5kIGhlaWdodD0iNDIiIHNwbGl0VHlwZT0iU3RyZXRjaCIvPgoJPC9zdW1tYXJ5Pgo8L2phc3BlclJlcG9ydD4K
35
</content><type>jrxml</type></jrxmlFile></reportUnit>
0
```

Updating a single jrxml file would require posting a **file** a la

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/jasperserver-pro/rest_v2/resources/public/TestJrxmlFile_files/main_jrxml?createFolders=true&overwrite=true HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/repository.file+xml
User-Agent: Jersey/2.13 (Apache HttpClient 4.3.4)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=CBE64F76548FC2D4CB73281A6FEB9319; userLocale=en_US
Cookie2: $Version=1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

93a
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><file><creationDate>2015-11-13T09:59:55</creationDate><label>Main jrxml</label><permissionMask>1</permissionMask><updateDate>2015-11-13T09:59:55</updateDate><uri>/public/TestJrxmlFile_files/main_jrxml</uri><version>0</version><content>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    dodD0iNDIiIHNwbGl0VHlwZT0iU3RyZXRjaCIvPgoJPC9zdW1tYXJ5Pgo8L2phc3BlclJlcG9ydD4K
23
</content><type>jrxml</type></file>
0
```

Comment: Thanks!. Is the gzipping part mandatory or it's just to save payload size? Is there a way to send just xml payload?

Comment: It's not mandatory - it's to save payload. This specifically is an example of how the JasperStudio application sends the jrxml files to the repository.