# How to generate localized report in JasperReports Server?

Tags: internationalization, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I've created a jrxml report file. I've added the resourceBundles (pl_PL, en_GB and en_US and the default one also in english) named test.properties, test_pl_PL.properties and so on. And I have added resourceBundle="test" propertety to the  tag. I've deployed the report and all related resources.

I am generating my report through rest API v2, namely:

http://localhost:9000/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/test_summary.pdf

How do I steer in which locale the report is generated? I've tried the Accept-Language in the header (through postman), also I've tried Chrome extensions and Firefox and Opera for all these clientes the report is generated in pl_PL. The only exception is edge browser in which the report is generated in english (default) locale.

Comment: You can check this posts: [Creating a Locale](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-administration-guide/v561/creating-locale) & [How to specify JasperReports Server locale in URL](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-specify-jasperreports-server-locale-url) & [Configuring JasperReports Server to Offer a Locale](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-administration-guide/v561/configuring-jasperreports-server-offer)

Comment: Another: [How to set the locale of the running report via rest_v2 webservice?](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/802231/how-set-locale-running-report-restv2-webservice) & [Rest v1 web service: Set the report output locale](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/803401/rest-v1-web-service-set-report-output-locale) & [JasperReport Server REST 2 api - Creating a new report](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33491424/876298)

Comment: That works for me: http://localhost:9000/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/test_summary.pdf&userLocale=pl_PL  , so please post the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass *Locale* via ***`userLocale`*** parameter in *URL*. Like this:

```
http://localhost:9000/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/test.pdf&userLocale=pl_PL
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, many years after initial question, but anyway: report itself has an embedded parameter `REPORT_LOCALE`. You could set it as usual, trough URL. Example:
`https://example.com/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/folder/Invoice.pdf?REPORT_LOCALE=bg_BG&InvoiceId=2`